# Undefined Promise from MailComposer.composeAsync(options)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am making an android app on snack expo, that will download a .mobi file from the internet, attach it to email draft, and delete the .mobi file afterwards.

[link to the snack just in case](https://snack.expo.dev/x9cDfhXe0)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as MailComposer from 'expo-mail-composer';


 
export default function App() {
 
const [stxt, setStxt] = useState("123");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{stxt}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{data}</Text>
      <Button title="Send" onPress={btnclicked}/>
    </View>
  );
}

let data = "outside app() const text";

const btnclicked = () => {
  FileSystem.downloadAsync('https://filesamples.com/samples/ebook/mobi/sample1.mobi',FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'test.mobi')
  .then(({ uri }) => {MailComposer.composeAsync({recipients:["test@gmail.com"], attachments:[uri]}); })
  .then(({ res }) => {console.log(res)} )
  .catch(error => {console.error(error);});
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

On the Expo docs, it says that the MailComposer.composeAsync(options) function will return a promise MailComposerStatus showing whether the email draft was cancelled, saved, sent or undetermined.

But the promise (line 27) I get is always undefined, therefore I cannot chain the .then to delete the .mobi file (presumably using FileSystem.moveAsync(options) ).

I just need to make sure the .mobi file is well attached to the email draft before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an unnecessary set of braces around MailComposer call which causes the function block to return null and you are also not chaining the `.then` correctly.

It should be something like

```
.then(
  ({ uri }) => MailComposer.composeAsync({ 
    recipients:["test@gmail.com"], 
    attachments:[uri] 
  }).then( 
    ({ res }) => {console.log(res)} 
  ))
```

I would just recommend using the async await pattern instead of dealing with .then callback chains